# HighStock won't force-group for a wider range than the data

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to aggregate weekly values in the middle of the week with HighStock. Granted, I don't have all the data yet (as this is still mid-week so not all the data for the week exists) so I'd like to aggregate whatever data that exists (start of the week till now).

Problem: When I use aggregation on a range wider than the existing data, HighStock would strike on me. 
When I force weekly sum it won't work - [just like in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ts4hQ/2/):

```
// works
[ 'minute',[1]]

// doens't work
[ 'hour',[1]]
```

Uncomment the the commented out line in the fiddle and it works again. Ideally, I would expect when I aggregate over a week from prev Wednesday to this Wednesday (a week's worth of time) to get 2 values: one for prev week, another for this week (since Monday).

Any ideas what should I be adding/changing to make it work?

Comment: I think it's a bug, reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2365). Thanks!